# Why does wiggling some thin metal objects back and forth cause them to snap?

Tags: material-science, metals

Why does wiggling some thin metal objects back and forth cause them to snap? For example, a paperclip. Is this a property shared across all metals, or only some?

Answer (score 4):

Bending a metal adds defects to the material.
As defects accumulate, the metal gets harder, stronger and more difficult to bend whilst at the same time getting hotter.
This is called [work hardening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_hardening).
However cracks also form leading to [fatigue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatigue_(material)) failure.

So try it with a metal ([ductile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ductility) material) paper clip and a plastic ([brittle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brittleness) material) paper clip.
You should find that even trying to straighten out a plastic paper clip breaks it whereas you can straighten out and cycle a metal paper clip many times before it breaks.
Also note it getting harder to bend the metal paper clip before it breaks and it getting hotter.